# What set are these parts from? Tan walls and arches with green shutters?

Tags: set-identification

Can you help me identify this Lego set? I don't know what set it is or how to build it!!

[image: photo of parts]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like bag five of the [Friends "Summer Riding Camp"](https://brickset.com/sets/3185-1/Summer-Riding-Camp) from a few years back. I'd guess it's the stable to the left hand side of this picture:

[image: Summer Riding Camp]

The combination of the dark green shutters and medium lavender plates were my driving clues.